# Removing local from group

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory

How I can restrict access to the client! It's seems like everyone in the root domain and trusted domain can access the client, I would like to restrict access for specific AD groups.

Comment: `How I can restrict access to the client!` what are you actually asking? Are you asking how to limit interactive logins to specific computers?

Comment: OP, don't mess with the special groups. Add it back like it was with `net localgroup` command.

Comment: @MDMarra: yes, exactly what I want. By now everyone in the domain can log on.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve with it?

Comment: @MDMarra: We have two domain A and B (trustesd), where we use domain B to retrieve the users to domain A. The reason I will limit is because everyone in Domain B has access to the client, which should not be. This is because of accessibility control of applications and only a certain group can access, etc.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you're asking but it sounds to me like you may want to reconfigure the trust to use Selective Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to tackle this is with group policy IMO.

Deny Local log in, group policy:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957048.aspx

You could just remove "users" from the "allow log on locally" group.

If you're only talking about one computer, the easiest way to do it would be to do the following:

1. Create an ad group
2. edit the computers local gpo 
   a. remove "users" from the "allow logon locally"
   b. add the group that you created in ad

If you're talking about multiple computers

1. create an ad group
2. put the computers into an OU
3. create a GPO and apply it to the OU.

Comment: see my edit, let me know if that clears it up.

Comment: Without any issue?  I couldn't promise that.  You need to understand the way GP works and what the policies are doing.  what are you concerned about exactly and what are you doing specifically?

Comment: This solution works very well, but remote installation does not work even if you Enable PSRemoting on client. (The administrator group are also added in "allow logon locally"). Is there any other solution?

Comment: i'm not sure what to tell you.  I've provided the info that i know and that has worked for me.